# Can't create node with properties here. It already exists in this context

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher, neo4jphp

I am getting the following error:

```
Can't create `referee` with properties here. It already exists in this context
```

when I execute the following:

```
foreach($feedarray as $feed)
            {

            $game= $client->makeNode();
            $game->setProperty('label', "Game: ".$feed['game_number'])
                    ->setProperty('type', "game")
                    ->setProperty('referee_name',$disposition['referee_name'])     
             ->save();

$queryString = "START referee=node:node_auto_index(name={name}), game=node({nodeId}) ".
                           "CREATE UNIQUE (referee{label:{name}, type:'referee'})-[:REFEREED{ label:'REFEREED' }]->(game)".
                           "RETURN referee";
            $query = new Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $queryString, array('nodeId' => $game->getId(),'name' => $feed['referee_name']));
            $result = $query->getResultSet();
                }

}//for loop
```

Comment: Does the referee node already exist in your database?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is because you have already bound to the identifier "referee" in the START portion of the query.

You should not need the START referee=... in your query because CREATE UNIQUE will find it by the properties supplied, or create it.